# AllowOverride None, and .htaccess works

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Well, this is not a problem yet, but I don't understand why Apache is reading the `.htaccess` files... I do:

```
grep -R "AllowOverride" /etc
```

and I have:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:# for additional configuration directives.  See also the      AllowOverride
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default:       AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default:       AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default:   #   AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default:#        AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl:       AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl:       AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl:       AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl:       AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/conf.d/security:#  AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/conf.d/localized-error-pages:#        AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/mods-available/userdir.conf:                AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
/etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf:    AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:     AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:     AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default: #   AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:#        AllowOverride None
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.conf:    AllowOverride None
grep: /etc/blkid.tab: No such file or directory
```

Seems I have no AllowOverride all, so why is it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you have:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/userdir.conf:  AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
```

Although this is related to the userdir configuration, the `FileInfo` override is the bare minimum for apache to read htaccess files, within that context.

In the [AllowOverride documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride), we have:

> **FileInfo**
>
> Allow use of the directives controlling document types (DefaultType, ErrorDocument, ForceType, LanguagePriority, SetHandler, SetInputFilter, SetOutputFilter, and mod_mime Add* and Remove* directives, etc.), document meta data (Header, RequestHeader, SetEnvIf, SetEnvIfNoCase, BrowserMatch, CookieExpires, CookieDomain, CookieStyle, CookieTracking, CookieName), mod_rewrite directives (RewriteEngine, RewriteOptions, RewriteBase, RewriteCond, RewriteRule), mod_alias directives (Redirect, RedirectTemp, RedirectPermanent, RedirectMatch), and Action from mod_actions.

When the **AllowOverride** is anything except "None", the htaccess file will be read and depending on the override options, certain statements in the htaccess file will be honored. It just so happens that the `FileInfo` option covers a lot of the frequently used directives in an htaccess file.

Comment: All right, thanks. Sorry for not searching properly. It wasn't so difficult to find... Well, in my case I'm giving to htaccess files, the privileges to use all directives except Options and XBitHack. Right?